# UK Settlement VISA - Questions

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, eu-spouses

My UK settlement VISA got confirmed few days back and I have to go to UK for the Bio-metric testing. I have few questions related to this particular category of UK settlement VISA.My spouse is a British Citizen who is currently working in UK and she only applied for this VISA for me.

My concerns
1) Due to family responsibilities (I have an extended family including ailing parents and other close relatives, who are completely dependent on me) i cannot relocate to UK for a longer duration. I am needed at my home country at regular intervals to take care of my parents and relatives.  My intention is to work partly from UK and partly from my home country to take care of my dependent parents - Is this possible with this UK settlement VISA ?

2) I do not want to bring my parents and relatives to UK since they won't be comfortable with the new surroundings and various health reasons.

3) I have good job in my home country and my present employer will allow to have a flexible working location - My question is can I continue my present job in my home country and commute between UK and home country at regular intervals .

4) Is there any restriction on travel for this VISA. i.e I plan to be in UK for 1 months and 2 months in my home country - Is this agreeable for the UK Immigration ?

5) Is there any other restriction for this particular Settlement UK visa?

Comment: You’ve already asked pretty much the same question and received an answer here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142085/uk-settlement-visa-spouse-rules The Visa you hold is for those who intend to settle permanently in the UK. Your proposal to keep your job in your home country, commute to the UK and spend twice the time in your home country as in the UK doesn’t seem to me to be compatible with the terms of your visa. I’d suggest you talk to an Immigration lawyer

Comment: Additionally, when you applied for your visa how did you present your intentions regarding retaining your overseas job and spending significantly more time outside the UK than in it? IANAL however if you didn’t mention any of it but just put a vanilla case forward to join your spouse in the UK, there may be a possibility that you didn’t disclose material facts See S-EC.2.2. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-fm-family-members

Comment: “I have to go to the UK for the biometric-testing” - where did you apply from? You’d normally be asked to give biometrics in the UK only if you applied from within the UK. Otherwise you’d be asked to go to a visa application centre https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/personal-data At this stage of the process, do you have the correct travel documentation to enter the UK?